# does the curly braces change the reading of this function

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, reduce

I was writing a function to flatten an array from eloquent javascript using the concat and reduce methods. When i write my code like this:

```
    function flatten(args){
       return args.reduce((current,i) =>{
           current.concat(i);
       },[] );
   }

   let arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
   console.log(flatten(arrays));
```

i get the following error:

```
current.concat(i);
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
```

but when i get rid of the curly braces '{}' in this section:

before:

```
return args.reduce((current,i) =>{
        current.concat(i);
    },[] );
```

after:

```
return args.reduce((current,i) =>
        current.concat(i)
    ,[] );
}
```

it prints out just fine. This format works fine when finding a sum with an initialization of 0. does the concat method not recognize the [] when it is within the curly braces '{}'.

Comment: I think with the curly braces you need to have return current.concat(i), not just current.concat(i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes it is different. Your reducer needs to return a value in the function. The value of the `current` parameter is equal to the last return from the invocation of the last reduce function call. In the first invocation, the `current` parameter is equal to the initial value specified in the second parameter to the reduce function call (i.e. `[]`).

Explicitly returning `current` with the braced version would fix the issue as well:

```
function flatten(args) {
   return args.reduce((current, i) => {
       return current.concat(i);
   }, []);
}
```

Without the curly braces, the return is implicitly returning the value returned by the concat expression, which is a new array.

For more information on how arrow functions work, check out [MDN's Arrow functions article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Specifically, this section talks about how it's implied:

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: => { return expression; }
```

As well as this section:

```
// When the only statement in an arrow function is `return`, we can remove `return` and remove
// the surrounding curly brackets
elements.map(element => element.length); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```